# Online C# code beautifier

Tags: web-apps, c#, code-beautification

Is there an online C# beautifier that is easy to paste-beautify-copy from?

I am looking for one that has options for:

- Indentation (4 spaces, n spaces, tab char, etc)
- Curly braces placement (on the statement line, on own line)

Much like [Jsbeautier](http://jsbeautifier.org/), but for C#.

Comment: Any particular reason you want it to be online rather than a program on your computer?

Comment: @NickWilde because the code I mostly beautify is copypasted from SO posts which have pieces of code that do not compile or are errenous by themselves, so that is out of the question.

Comment: I would expect that there are some plugins that could do that without compiling but I see what you mean

Comment: Oh, wait, you mean why not offline if there could be such a program. No reason why not, really, but online could be much more accessible and not require additional installation, which is nice if my notebook isn't with me.

Answer (score 2):

[C# Formatter Online](http://www.freecodeformat.com/c-format.php)

Pros:

- Correct beautify.
- Online.
- Input C# code and copy/paste c# beautified code.
- Download .cs beautified version.

Cons:

- Only two options for formatting fonts: `small` and `big`.
- K&R bracing, which is not usual C# formatting.

Comment: K&R bracing was exactly what I've been looking for. Huge surprise for me that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

[C# Viewer](http://codebeautify.org/csharpviewer)

It does not really have any of the extra options that you want. However it does very nicely beautify - and also minify - C# code.

It also lets you one click download the code as a *.cs file and load C# code to process from a file or web location as well as Copy/Paste.

Comment: This is nice and it has some auto-formatted editing capabilities, but editing the beautified code messes up the space characters and it doesn't have options for curly braces or any other options at that.

Comment: Yeah that's what I saw but I'm not aware of any other options (I used it fair while ago for some SO code myself but since I rarely use C# I haven't had much inclination to search for something better.

Answer (score 1):

Although it has to be installed a better solution is to use [SublimeAStyleFormatter](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter) - which is a [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) Plugin.

You have to first install [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (painless) and then install SublimeAStyleFormatter which is also quite painless. There are a couple methods you can use to install it (all of which are detailed in [the readme](http://www.sublimetext.com/)) but I recommend the Package Control method as very easy.

There are quite a few options:

- `indent`
- `indent-spaces`
- and [lots more](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter/blob/master/options_default.json)

Answer (score -3):

I would use the online c# formatter http://codebeautify.org/csharpviewer where I can formate as well as share my code as public or private.

Comment: That answer was already given